# Cómo entregar el parámetro spring.config.location a WinSW al instalar un JAR SpringBoot como servicio Windows?

Tags: windows, spring-boot, servicio, winsw

Estoy intentando usar WinSW para instalar un JAR de Spring Boot como servicio de Windows en Windows10. Logro que funcione si en los argumentos le doy sólo el nombre del JAR.

```
<service>
    <id>testSB/id>
    <name>testSB</name>
    <description>This service runs a spring boot JAR as service.</description>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <startmode>Automatic</startmode>
    <delayedAutoStart>true</delayedAutoStart>
    <onfailure action="restart" delay="10 sec"/>
    <onfailure action="restart" delay="20 sec"/>
    <onfailure action="none"/>
    <resetfailure>1 hour</resetfailure>
    <arguments>-jar "myjar-1.0.0.jar" </arguments>
    <log mode="roll-by-size-time">
      <sizeThreshold>20480</sizeThreshold>
      <pattern>yyyyMMdd</pattern>
      <autoRollAtTime>00:30:00</autoRollAtTime>
      <zipOlderThanNumDays>5</zipOlderThanNumDays>
    </log>
    <logpath>%BASE%/logs</logpath>
</service>
```

FUnciona y veo la página principal del servicio.

**Pero, si le añado --spring.config.location=application.yml para que use ese archivo externo de configuración, el servicio no arranca.**

```
<service>
    <id>testSB/id>
    <name>testSB</name>
    <description>This service runs a spring boot JAR as service.</description>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <startmode>Automatic</startmode>
    <delayedAutoStart>true</delayedAutoStart>
    <onfailure action="restart" delay="10 sec"/>
    <onfailure action="restart" delay="20 sec"/>
    <onfailure action="none"/>
    <resetfailure>1 hour</resetfailure>
    <arguments>-jar "myjar-1.0.0.jar" --spring.config.location=./application.yml</arguments>
    <log mode="roll-by-size-time">
      <sizeThreshold>20480</sizeThreshold>
      <pattern>yyyyMMdd</pattern>
      <autoRollAtTime>00:30:00</autoRollAtTime>
      <zipOlderThanNumDays>5</zipOlderThanNumDays>
    </log>
    <logpath>%BASE%/logs</logpath>
</service>
```

Ya probé con ruta relativa `./app.yml`, usando la variable %BASE%: `%BASE%/app.yml`, con la ruta absoluta: `C:\path\to\app.yml`. Siempre falla y los logs sólo dicen:

```
2020-09-21 16:57:25,626 DEBUG - Completed. Exit code is 0
2020-09-21 16:57:30,560 DEBUG - Starting WinSW in console mode
2020-09-21 16:57:30,930 DEBUG - User requested the status of the process with id 'testSB'
2020-09-21 16:57:30,932 DEBUG - Completed. Exit code is 0
2020-09-21 16:57:35,363 DEBUG - Starting WinSW in service mode
2020-09-21 16:57:35,380 INFO  - Starting java -jar "myjar-1.0.0.jar" --spring.config.location=C:\path\to\application.yml
2020-09-21 16:57:35,395 DEBUG - Completed. Exit code is 0
```

El Visor de Eventos de Windows muestra un error cada vez que lo intento arrancar, que dice:

```
Service cannot be started. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at WinSW.Util.ProcessHelper.StartProcessAndCallbackForExit(Process processToStart, String executable, String arguments, Dictionary`2 envVars, String workingDirectory, Nullable`1 priority, ProcessCompletionCallback callback, Boolean redirectStdin, LogHandler logHandler, Boolean hideWindow)
   at WinSW.WrapperService.StartProcess(Process processToStart, String arguments, String executable, LogHandler logHandler, Boolean redirectStdin)
   at WinSW.WrapperService.OnStart(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)
```

Alguien sabe cómo arranco ese JAR como servicio diciéndole que use ese yml?? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente probé ésto, actualizando WinSW a 2.11 y revisando que la versión de .NET disponible estuviese soportada.

La configuración relativa a donde está el exe de WinSW funciona correctamente.

PD. Comenté la línea de autoRoll porque estaba haciendo que Windows Server reportara el servicio como detenido, incluso si la instancia de java seguía en ejecución. Por ahí está el issue en el github del proyecto.

```
<service>
    <id>testSB</id>
    <name>testSB</name>
    <description>This service runs something.</description>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <arguments>
        -Xmx100MB
        -Xms100MB
        -XX:+UseG1GC
        -jar "myjar.jar"
        --spring.config.location=./application.yml
    </arguments>
    <startmode>Automatic</startmode>
    <delayedAutoStart>false</delayedAutoStart>
    <depend>someOtherService</depend>
    <onfailure action="restart" delay="10 sec"/>
    <onfailure action="restart" delay="20 sec"/>
    <onfailure action="none"/>
    <resetfailure>1 hour</resetfailure>
    <logpath>%BASE%/logs</logpath>
    <log mode="roll-by-size-time">
        <sizeThreshold>20480</sizeThreshold>
        <pattern>yyyyMMdd</pattern>
        <!--<autoRollAtTime>00:30:00</autoRollAtTime>-->
        <zipOlderThanNumDays>5</zipOlderThanNumDays>
    </log>
</service>
```